# Where to type pgsql2shp command

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgsql2shp

How to convert post gis database into shapefile, I found that I need to use pgsql2shp command on postgis database query , But how to use it and where to use it. Do I have to use it in the postgre sql database command line or in the normal command line?

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE, you need to specify what operating system and version you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I am using linux 2.6.18. When I type pgsql2shp in command line I get an error saying command not found.

Comment: It will be in wherever your postgres bin directory is, in my case,`/usr/local/pgsql/bin/shp2pgsql`. It might also be in `/usr/bin/` or symlinked to the same. If you add your postgres install dir to your path, then you should be able to call pgsql2shp from anywhere.

Comment: You need to install postgis locally to get this command.

Comment: I have it installed but still its not working

Comment: How did you install it? On what Linux distribution?

Comment: I could see /usr/local/pgsql/bin/shp2pgsql in my system and I cd into this place and type shp2pgsql it says command not found. How to add postgres install dir to my path?

Answer (score 3):

The [PostgreSQL Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-post.html#AEN25658) explains how to add the path to binaries to the `PATH` environment variable. This procedure depends on your OS distribution and how you installed PostgreSQL and/or PostGIS.

---

Otherwise, if you want to run a program like `shp2pgsql` without adding it to `PATH`, the  path to the binary needs to be specified:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/shp2pgsql example.shp public.example > example.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postGIS 2.x, and all is installed and configured properly, you can also run `shp2pgsql-gui` from the bash.
In the window dialog select the tab "Export": now you are able to extract a postGIS table to shapefile format.